# Unity C# tap and swipe on android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, swipe

I'm currently wiritng a simple game in unity with obstacles, it is an endless game and the player can jump, move to right and left in order to avoid these obstacles. The game works with asus and huawei devices but on samsung doesn't. With samsung devices the player doesn't jump when I tap the screen but the swipe works.

My code:

```
void change()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)

    {

        Touch touch = Input.touches[0];



        switch (touch.phase)

        {

            case TouchPhase.Began:

                startPos = touch.position;

                break;



            case TouchPhase.Ended:



                float swipeDistHorizontal = (new Vector3(touch.position.x, 0, 0) - new Vector3(startPos.x, 0, 0)).magnitude;

                if (swipeDistHorizontal > minSwipeDistX)

                {

                    float swipeValue = Mathf.Sign(touch.position.x - startPos.x);

                    if (swipeValue > 0)
                        {//right swipe

                        anim.Play(change_Line_Animation);
                        transform.localPosition = second_PosOfPlayer;

                        SoundManager.instance.PlayMoveLineSound();

                    }
                    else if (swipeValue < 0)
                    {//left swipe

                        anim.Play(change_Line_Animation);
                        transform.localPosition = first_PosOfPlayer;

                        SoundManager.instance.PlayMoveLineSound();

                    }


                }

                else {

                      if (!player_Jumped){

                          anim.Play(jump_Animation);
                          player_Jumped = true;

                          SoundManager.instance.PlayJumpSound();
                      }

                }

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This function is called in the update() function.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am new here, I cannot use comments to ask for further questions yet.
What exactly does not work when using Samsung?

You could simplify the computations though.

```
                float swipeValue = touch.position.x - startPos.x; //Mathf.Sign(touch.position.x - startPos.x);

                if (swipeValue > 0)
                    {//right swipe

                    anim.Play(change_Line_Animation);
                    transform.localPosition = second_PosOfPlayer;

                    SoundManager.instance.PlayMoveLineSound();

                }
                else if (swipeValue < 0)
                {//left swipe

                    anim.Play(change_Line_Animation);
                    transform.localPosition = first_PosOfPlayer;

                    SoundManager.instance.PlayMoveLineSound();

                }
```

You do not need Math.Sign when only comparing to > or < than 0.

```
            case TouchPhase.Began:

              startPos = touch.position.x; // startPos could be float

            break;
```

and hence,

```
float swipeDistHorizontal = Mathf.Abs(touch.position.x - startPos);
```

If the game uses only horizontal swiping, you do not need vectors to store and compute swipe delta.

If you provide more information, I am happy to help more.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will try yor code later. In samsung the player doesn't jump (so tap doesn't work) but he can move left and right (so swipe works)

Comment: I didn't see the defintion of minSwipeDistX, but I think it should be screen size relative, not a constant value for all devices. Something like a fraction of Screen.width.
It is possible that the minSwipeDistX is just a too low value for that device and while tapping screen the finger moves across that range.
Maybe you could try TouchPhase.Stationary for that.

Comment: I defined it in this way:  public float minSwipeDistX;
With TouchPhase.Stationary the problem persists

Comment: Okay. What is the value assigned to minSwipeDistX?

Comment: It isn't set. is it should be equal to screen width?

Comment: It should be equal to a fraction of a screen width. E.g. 1/8 of screen width. It must be assigned a value, otherwise it would be 0 by default. It is advisable to assign it before the play, maybe in Awake function. Also, have you tried calling the TouchPhase.Stationary?

Comment: so in the awake: minSwipeDistX = 1/8*Screen.width
Right?
Yes, I added a case with TouchPhase.Stationary but it's the same

Comment: Have you tried debbuging on Samsung device with Unity Remote (Android App)?
Try adding a breakpoint right inside the TouchPhase.Ended code section and examine the variables. It will be easier to spot a bug if you simplify the code as I suggested before.

Comment: I add the value of minSwipeDistX and when I tap the screen the player doesn't jump but I can hear the JumpSound, so I guess that the device detects the tap but doesn't start the animation

Comment: Have you tried checking for whether animation says it is being played after calling Play method? 
anim.Play(change_Line_Animation);
Debug.Log("Animation playing?  " + anim.isPlaying.ToString());

Comment: Example on huawei: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P4gTY5Z07aAQOehGYQmnc434YEPFSfNN/view?usp=sharing
On samsung: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cV90l_375T5jH5AiVVFlGGDa_VK_QGmz/view

Comment: I would maybe try anim.Play(jump_Animation, PlayMode.StopAll); 
Maybe if you post more code, we could find the bug.

Comment: This is the code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Snk3xIwnblOEP9ghZJtnQejhV9nEXeIY

Comment: I get an error when I use anim.Play(jump_Animation, PlayMode.StopAll);
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.PlayMode' to 'int'

Comment: Hey man, I solved the problem setting minSwipeDistX to 0,125*Screen.width and change it to double. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to hear. Sorry I've been busy today and didn't have time to examine the entire project you shared on Google drive. You can mark the answer so that question no longer appears among unsolved questions. Happy coding.